# Estado HTTP 404 - JBoss

Tags: jsp, jboss

Estoy corriendo un proyecto en `JSP` sobre `JBoss` configurado en eclipse, y me genera el siguiente error:

> Estado HTTP 404 - /sidetweb
>   type Informe de estado
>
> mensaje /sidetweb
>
> descripción El recurso requerido (/sidetweb) no está disponible.
>
> JBoss Web/7.0.13.Final

En consola no se muestra nada raro:

```
06:55:35,840 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
06:55:36,032 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
06:55:36,069 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" starting
06:55:36,854 INFO  [org.xnio] XNIO Version 3.0.3.GA
06:55:36,854 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] JBAS015888: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
06:55:36,870 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.3.GA
06:55:36,877 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] JBoss Remoting version 3.2.3.GA
06:55:36,924 INFO  [org.jboss.as.logging] JBAS011502: Removing bootstrap log handlers
06:55:36,976 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 44) JBAS013101: Activating Security Subsystem
06:55:36,992 INFO  [org.jboss.as.osgi] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) JBAS011940: Activating OSGi Subsystem
06:55:36,995 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 27) JBAS010404: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (version 5.1)
06:55:37,004 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 27) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
06:55:37,004 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 31) JBAS010280: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
06:55:37,016 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS010408: Starting JCA Subsystem (JBoss IronJacamar 1.0.9.Final)
06:55:37,016 INFO  [org.jboss.as.configadmin] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 26) JBAS016200: Activating ConfigAdmin Subsystem
06:55:37,034 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) JBAS015537: Activating WebServices Extension
06:55:37,040 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 38) JBAS011800: Activating Naming Subsystem
06:55:37,070 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS011802: Starting Naming Service
06:55:37,100 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS013100: Current PicketBox version=4.0.7.Final
06:55:37,164 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015400: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
06:55:37,213 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management.AbstractServerConfig] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.0.2.GA
06:55:37,443 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory C:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\deployments
06:55:37,446 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015002: Deployment of 'sidetwebEAR.ear' requested, but the deployment is not present
06:55:37,447 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015003: Found sidetweb.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called sidetweb.war.dodeploy
06:55:37,493 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS017100: Listening on /127.0.0.1:9999
06:55:37,495 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS017100: Listening on localhost/127.0.0.1:4447
06:55:37,501 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-2) Arrancando Coyote HTTP/1.1 en puerto http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080
06:55:37,601 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
06:55:37,737 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
06:55:37,738 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015874: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" started in 2143ms - Started 134 of 209 services (74 services are passive or on-demand)
```

Configuración del web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0"xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
 <display-name>sidetweb</display-name>
    <servlet>
       <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
          <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
           <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
       <welcome-file>/index.jsp</welcome-file>
   </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Te está dando este mensaje: `Deployment of 'sidetwebEAR.ear' requested, but the deployment is not present`. Verifica que el recurso para levantar el servicio esté bien configurado. Por alguna razón no consigue el archivo.

Comment: ¿De casualidad sabes donde se configura tal recurso? He estado buscando y no doy con él.